# Crash on Read AVAudioFile Buffer Create Waves Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiofile

I have been working in AVAudioPlayer and draw a wave. I am using [AudioArmada](https://github.com/cwalo/AudioArmada/tree/90f214d3d9483e817cdb1396e08f8f626a7be821) Github pods to draw waves With the help of `AudioArmada Pods`. But Some Cases AVAudioFile Crash on reading buffer time.

**Code Below:**

```
public func openFile(_ file: URL) {
    let audioFile = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: file)
    // specify the format we WANT for the buffer
    let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: audioFile.fileFormat.sampleRate, channels: audioFile.fileFormat.channelCount, interleaved: false)
    // initialize and fill the buffer
    let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format!, frameCapacity: UInt32(audioFile.length))
    try! audioFile.read(into: buffer!)
    // copy buffer to readFile struct
    readFile.floatValuesLeft = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: buffer?.floatChannelData?[0], count:Int(buffer!.frameLength)))
    readFile.populated = true
    reload(zoomFactor: zoomFactor)
}

public func reload(zoomFactor: Float = 1.0) {
    self.zoomFactor = zoomFactor
    setNeedsDisplay()
}

func drawSoundcloudWaveform(_ rect: CGRect) {
  let path = UIBezierPath()
  path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: rect.height/2))
  var index = 0
  while index < readFile.leftPoints.count {
  let point = readFile.leftPoints[index]
  let drawFrom = CGPoint(x: point.x, y: path.currentPoint.y)
  path.move(to: drawFrom)
  let drawPointBottom = CGPoint(x: point.x, y: path.currentPoint.y + (point.y))
   path.addLine(to: drawPointBottom)
   path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: drawPointBottom.x + pixelWidth, y: drawPointBottom.y))
   path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: drawFrom.x + pixelWidth, y: drawFrom.y))
   path.close()
   path.move(to: drawFrom)
   let drawPointTop = CGPoint(x: point.x, y: path.currentPoint.y - (point.y))
   path.addLine(to: drawPointTop)
   path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: drawPointTop.x + pixelWidth, y: drawPointTop.y))
   path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: drawFrom.x + pixelWidth, y: drawFrom.y))
   path.close()
   index = index + Int(pixelWidth) + Int(pixelSpacing)
   }
    UIColor(red:0.21, green:0.77, blue:0.78, alpha:1.0).set()
    path.stroke()
    path.fill()
}
```

**Below Cases:**

1. Running Case:

   ```
   guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Beat9", withExtension: ".mp3") else { return }
   openFile(file) 

   AVAudioPCMBuffer Output:  AVAudioPCMBuffer@0x6000005c9300: 0/35864064 bytes
   ```

**Wave Screen Shot:**

[image: Running Case Screen Shot]

2. Crash Case:

   ```
   guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "IshqMubarak", withExtension: ".mp3") else { return }
   openFile(file)

   AVAudioPCMBuffer Output: AVAudioPCMBuffer@0x600003eb1180: 0/0 bytes // i m confused why show zero bytes buffer
   ```

> **Error:**   Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Foundation._GenericObjCError.nilError: file /Users/apple/Desktop/AudioArmada-90f214d3d9483e817cdb1396e08f8f626a7be821/AudioArmada/Classes/WaveformZoomable.swift, line 63

**Question:** How to solve this issue and why crash on some times?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm no expert on audio programming, but this line — 'Foundation._GenericObjCError.nilError' — makes me think that you've had some problem accessing the file. Either the file isn't there, or it's corrupt, or it's in an unreadable format; something is happening which makes the app think the file has zero length, and the error arises because you're trying to buffer data that doesn't exist.

Comment: okay @TedWrigley i will check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing the error it's crashing at line 63 of WaveformZoomable.swift of  **AudioArmada** where `try!` is used on a *nil* object.

[AVAudioFile](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiofile/1388043-read)  throws (same for line 56):

```
func read(into buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer) throws
```

---

You can use

- `try?` to get rid of crash for now
- or `try` `catch` to find the reason why it's not able to read
- and file an issue on [AudioArmada](https://github.com/cwalo/AudioArmada/tree/90f214d3d9483e817cdb1396e08f8f626a7be821)